# Using AMPScript to change the first character in a paragraph variable to lowercase

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, ampscript

```
%%[
IF Not Empty(@FirstName) and Not Empty(@BodyHeading) THEN
    SET @BodyHeading = Concat(@FirstName," ," ,"  ", Lowercase(@BodyHeading))
]%%
```

Outputs this:

```
Firstname, getting started on the road can be pretty expensive when you're young. to help, we compare more than 130 providers so you can find the best deal for you.
```

---

It has dropped all uppercase characters to lower but as it is a paragraph of text I only want to change the case of the first character, can anyone help?

Comment: Have you looked at the [Substring()](https://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/utilities_ampscript_functions/#substring) and [Length()](https://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/utilities_ampscript_functions/#length) AMPScript functions?

Comment: I looked at substring, but I got a parenthesis error - too many parenthesis - perhaps I had written it out wrong - still trying to figure it out with substring though

Answer (score 2):

This works, though there may be a better answer.

```
IF Not Empty(@FirstName) and Not Empty(@BodyHeading) THEN
    SET @BodyHeading = Concat(@FirstName,", " ,Lowercase(Substring(@BodyHeading,1,1)), Substring(@BodyHeading,2,Length(@BodyHeading)))
ENDIF
```

Comment: Paul, you are a legend! Thank you so much, works perfectly.